Asymptotics of hyperrgeometric 2F1 for large integer parameters
I have stumbled upon $$\frac{\Gamma(n+\frac{1}{2})\Gamma(n-\frac{1}{2})}{\Gamma(2n+1)} \ {}_2F_1\left(n+\frac{1}{2}, \ n-\frac{1}{2}; \ 2n+1, \ z\right)$$
Where the integer $n \to \infty$.  I need to determine the asymptotic expression of this with this condition. I can do that for the gamma function part using Stirling's approximation, but I haven't found any way to determine
$${}_2F_1\left(n+\frac{1}{2}, \ n-\frac{1}{2}; \ 2n+1, \ z\right) \ \ \text{for } \ \ n \to \infty.$$
How do I obtain this?
Any derivation or reference to the asymptotics of this specific parameters would be very helpful.

Some edits:


Did I answer your question?

Did I answer your question?

I am very sorry for a late response because I was into obtaining a few results along this line and I had an easier solution which I am adding as the edit. But this has numerical instability near h=1 as I implement it in mathematica. For that I had to revisit your answer and although it hasn't answered it completely but it is heading towards that.

Your argument is completely formal and non-rigorous. Note also that $\frac{{\Gamma (N)}}{{\Gamma \left( {N - \frac{1}{2}} \right)\sqrt N }} \sim 1$ as $N\to+\infty$.

You are also missing a factor of $(1-z)^{1/4}$ (which should be due to the non-rigorous argument). Take a look at the final result in my answer. I also did some numerical experiments and the formula I provided works.

Thank you for your very valuable answer and the edit, I will surely look into it. It does clarify better.

With $z = \cosh \zeta$, $\lambda  = n$, $\alpha  = \frac{1}{2}$, $\beta  = \frac{1}{2}$, and $\gamma  = 2$, the first result in $\S9$ of G. N. Watson's paper Asymptotic expansions of hypergeometric functions gives
\begin{align*}
\left( {\operatorname{csch} \!\big(  \tfrac{\zeta }{2}  \big)} \right)^{2n + 1} & {}_2F_1\!\left( {n + \tfrac{1}{2},n - \tfrac{1}{2};2n + 1; - \operatorname{csch}^2\! \big(  \tfrac{\zeta }{2} \big)} \right) \\ &\sim \frac{{2\Gamma (2n + 1)}}{{\Gamma \!\left( {n - \frac{1}{2}} \right)\Gamma \!\left( {n + \frac{3}{2}} \right)}}{\rm e}^{ - \left( {n + \frac{1}{2}} \right)\zeta } (1 - {\rm e}^{ - \zeta } )^{ - \frac{3}{2}} (1 + {\rm e}^{ - \zeta } )^{\frac{1}{2}} \sqrt {\frac{\pi }{n}} 
\\ &\sim 2^{2n+1}{\rm e}^{ - \left( {n + \frac{1}{2}} \right)\zeta } (1 - {\rm e}^{ - \zeta } )^{ - \frac{3}{2}} (1 + {\rm e}^{ - \zeta } )^{\frac{1}{2}} ,
\end{align*}
as $n\to+\infty$. Here $\zeta \in \left\{\xi: \operatorname{Re}(\xi)\ge 0,\, |\operatorname{Im}(\xi)|\le \pi \right\}$. Consequently,
\begin{align*}
{}_2F_1\!\left( n + \tfrac{1}{2},n - \tfrac{1}{2};2n + 1; - \operatorname{csch}^2 \!\big( \tfrac{\zeta }{2}\big) \right) & \sim \Big( {2\,{\rm e}^{ - \frac{\zeta }{2}} \sinh\! \big( \tfrac{\zeta }{2} \big)} \Big)^{2n + 1} (1 - {\rm e}^{ - \zeta } )^{ - \frac{3}{2}} (1 + {\rm e}^{ - \zeta } )^{\frac{1}{2}} \\ & = 
\coth ^{\frac{1}{2}} \!\big( \tfrac{\zeta }{2} \big)(1 - {\rm e}^{ - \zeta } )^{2n}
\end{align*}
as $n\to+\infty$. If we set $w=- \operatorname{csch}^2 \!\big( \tfrac{\zeta }{2}\big)$, then the domain of validity corresponds to $\left| \arg ( - w) \right| \le \pi$:
$$
{}_2F_1\!\left( n + \tfrac{1}{2},n - \tfrac{1}{2};2n + 1; w \right) \sim (1 - w)^{1/4} \left( \tfrac{1}{2} + \tfrac{1}{2}\sqrt {1 - w} \right)^{ - 2n}.
$$

Thank you username Gary for your insightful input but I think something easier is possible.

Dear username Gary, unfortunately the answer you provided gives me certain numerical instability near 1 but my previous result works there. I am more confused. Would you kindly explain why it might happen.

I had to ask WolframAlpha for many digits when $w$ is close to $1$ to confirm that my approximation is the correct one. Try to compute at least to $100$ decimal places to see the difference.

For example with $n=1000$ and $w=0.99$, the true value is $5.9604\ldots \times 10^{518}$, my approximation gives $5.9514\ldots \times 10^{518}$, whereas yours gives $1.8820\ldots \times 10^{519}$.

Any comments?$,!$

I am sorry to not respond to your valuable input as I am busy in between writing and applying to places. In my problem I have a function indexed by an even number and for each of such functions I need to evaluate the maxima near 1 of its argument. Physically that data should be power-law but your solution gives a random scatter of turning-points, while mine shows a straight line with slope 3/2 (numerically found ~ 1.55) in log-log plot. I admit that I do not fully understand it. I'm not sure if the optimization method I used played any important role here.

And I also admit that your answer is rigorously sound. That is where I am more confused.
